# freeRADIUS with LDAP SASL/Certificate based binding

Tags: freeradius

I am working on freeRADIUS v1.1.7-r0.0.2 with LDAP as backend for authenticating users.

I want to configure freeRADIUS server with certificates instead of using usernames and passwords.

How to configure RADIUS+LDAP using SASL/Certificate based binding ?

Please guide me how to achieve this,is there any help/doc how to configure LDAP SASL bind for RADIUS Server.

Answer (score 0):

Support for SASL binding was recently added in v3.0.x, both for administrative binds, and user binds, it's not available in previous versions.

See the SASL sections in the config [here](https://github.com/FreeRADIUS/freeradius-server/blob/v3.1.x/raddb/mods-available/ldap)

Certificated based binding has always been supported. It's configured with the `certificate_file` and `private_key_file` config items.

You cannot pass the SSL tunnel through from something like an EAP conversation.